# PHP Reading large tab delimited file looking for one line

Tags: php, fopen, csv

We get a product list from our suppliers delivered to our site by ftp. I need to create a script that searches through that file (tab delimited) for the products relevant to us and use the information to update stock levels, prices etc.

The file itself is something like 38,000 lines long and I'm wondering on the best way of handling this.
The only way I can think initially is using `fopen` and `fgetcsv` then cycling through each line. Putting the line into an array and looking for the relevant product code.
I'm hoping there is a much more efficient way (though I haven't tested the efficiency of this yet)

The file I'll be reading is 8.8 Mb.
All of this will need to be done automatically, e.g. by CRON on a daily basis.

Edit - more information.
I have run my first trial, and based on the 2 answers, I have the following code:
I have the items I need to pick out of the text file from the database in the array with `$items[$row['item_id']] = $row['prod_code'];`

```
$catalogue = file('catalogue.txt');
while ($line = $catalogue)
{
$prod = explode("   ",$line);
if (in_array($prod[0],$items))
    {
        echo $prod[0]."<br>";//will be updating the stock level in the db eventually
        }
}
```

Though this is not giving the correct output currently

Answer (score 0):

I used to do a similar thing with Dominos Pizza clocking in daily data (all UK).

Either load it all into a database in one go.

OR

Use fopen and load a line at a time into a database, keeping memory overheads low. (I had to use this method as the data wasn't formatted very well)

You can then query the database at your leisure.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by »I hope there is a more efficient way«? Effecient in respect to what? Writing the code? CPU consumption while executing the code? Disk I/O? Memory consumption?

Holding ~9MB of text in memory is not a problem (unless you've got a very low memory limit). A [file()](http://php.net/file) call would read the entire file and return an array (split by lines). This or [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/file_get_contents) will be the most efficient approach in respect to Disk I/O, but consume a lot more memory than necessary.

> Putting the line into an array and looking for the relevant product code.

I'm not sure why you would need to cache the contents of that file in an array. But if you do, remember that the array will use slightly more memory than the ~9MB of text. So you'd probably want to read the file sequentially, to avoid having the same data in memory twice.

Depending on what you want to do with the data, loading it into a database might be a viable solution as well, as @user1487944 already pointed out.

Comment: I've added some more information on my first attempt. I didn't get an output and the script eventually timed out